# How do you make a spring bean Primary only if another Primary bean does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to create multiple beans that implement the same interface.  I have a bean that I want to use as the "default" @Primary bean; however, since it acts as a default, I want another bean to be able to use @Primary (or something similar) to make a primary bean.  In other words, this default one should be like... "@PrimaryIfNoPrimaryAlreadyExist" kind of thing.  For example, I have this:

```
@Configuration
public class DefaultCustomObjectMapperConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ICustomObjectMapper defaultCustomObjectMapper(@Value("${objectmapper.serialize.defaultFormat:JSON}") String defaultMapperFormat,
                                                         @Qualifier(DEFAULT_XML_MAPPER_KEY) ICustomObjectMapper xmlMapper,
                                                         @Qualifier(DEFAULT_JSON_MAPPER_KEY) ICustomObjectMapper jsonMapper) {
        return "XML".equals(defaultMapperFormat) ? xmlMapper : jsonMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier(DEFAULT_JSON_MAPPER_KEY)
    public ICustomObjectMapper defaultJSONCustomObjectMapper() {
        return new DefaultCustomObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper());
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier(DEFAULT_XML_MAPPER_KEY)
    public ICustomObjectMapper defaultXMLCustomObjectMapper() {
        return new DefaultCustomObjectMapper(new XmlMapper());
    }
}
```

I *always* want to create the `defaultJSONCustomObjectMapper()` bean and the `defaultXMLCustomObjectMapper()` bean, but the `defaultCustomObjectMapper()` should only be created if there is not another bean in the Spring context that is defined as @Primary.  For example, it should not be created (or at least not used as Primary) if someone else defines this in the same context:

```
    @Primary
    @Bean
    ICustomObjectMapper anotherCustomObjectMapper() {
        return new AnotherCustomObjectMapper();
    }
```

I believe you can override a bean by calling it the same name, but I don't want to do it that way because then it requires the service pulling this in to know that it has to call the bean something special.

Is this possible? Or is there a way to do it that is better than this?

Edit:
Looking at the Spring annotations, there's the `ConditionalOnSingleCandidate`.  It would be more accurate for me to say I want the opposite of that, i.e. `ConditionalOnMultipleCandidates`

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Adding [@ConditionalOnMissingBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnMissingBean.html)(annotation = Primary.class) to your "default" @Primary bean should do the trick. This will only register your default primary bean if another primary bean of the same type is not already registered.</strike>

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(annotation = Primary.class)
public ICustomObjectMapper defaultCustomObjectMapper(@Value("${objectmapper.serialize.defaultFormat:JSON}") String defaultMapperFormat,
                                                     @Qualifier(DEFAULT_XML_MAPPER_KEY) ICustomObjectMapper xmlMapper,
                                                     @Qualifier(DEFAULT_JSON_MAPPER_KEY) ICustomObjectMapper jsonMapper) {
    // ...
}
```

Note that depending on the potential order of your other bean creation, you may want to ensure that this default bean is processed last. For example, by adding @Order(Integer.MAX_INT).

Update: Sean correctly points out that [@ConditionalOnMissingBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnMissingBean.html) doesn't work in this case because it looks for ANY bean with Primary annotation, not just beans of our type.

A somewhat ugly alternative is to programmatically set a bean to primary after bean creation if no other primary bean of that type was found. This can be done by implementing [BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.html) and [BeanFactoryAware](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactoryAware.html). Note that bean name is used, not qualifier.

```
@Configuration
public class DefaultCustomObjectMapperConfiguration 
    implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor, BeanFactoryAware {

    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Value("${objectmapper.serialize.defaultFormat:JSON}") 
    private String defaultMapperFormat;

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        // unused
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
        String[] beansOfType = BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors((ListableBeanFactory) beanFactory, ICustomObjectMapper.class);

        for(String beanName : beansOfType) {
            BeanDefinition beanDef = registry.getBeanDefinition(beanName);
            if(beanDef.isPrimary()) {
                // found an existing primary bean of same type
                return;
            }
        }
        
        // note that getBeanDefinition retrieves by bean name, which is not necessarily equal to qualifier
        BeanDefinition defaultPrimaryBeanDef = 
             registry.getBeanDefinition("XML".equals(defaultMapperFormat) ? DEFAULT_XML_MAPPER_KEY : DEFAULT_JSON_MAPPER_KEY);
        defaultPrimaryBeanDef.setPrimary(true);
    }


    @Bean(DEFAULT_JSON_MAPPER_KEY)
    @Qualifier(DEFAULT_JSON_MAPPER_KEY)
    public ICustomObjectMapper defaultJSONCustomObjectMapper() {
        return new DefaultCustomObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper());
    }

    @Bean(DEFAULT_XML_MAPPER_KEY)
    @Qualifier(DEFAULT_XML_MAPPER_KEY)
    public ICustomObjectMapper defaultXMLCustomObjectMapper() {
        return new DefaultCustomObjectMapper(new XmlMapper());
    }
}
```

Comment: Sweet! testing it out now.  As for the @Order, I thought the ConfiditionalOnMissingBean waits til the context is put together so that it knows if the bean exists or not?

Comment: Good point! The documentation mentions that the condition can only match the bean definitions that have been processed by the application context so far, so I'm not sure exactly how the precedence is handled without an explicit Order.

Comment: Something I'm noticing now is that that bean is never being created.  When I run a service that does not have its own ICustomObjectMapper bean, it is supposed to use defaultCustomObjectMapper as its primary, but instead I get an error because it finds the other 2, but not the primary (debug never hits code that instantiates the bean either)

Comment: I think the problem here is that it looks for all beans that have the Primary annotation, not just the ICustomObjectMappers that have it.  A workaround (not a valid solution) is to put all classes with a primary annotation on it... in the "ignored" element of the ConditionalOnMissingBean so that there are no other annotations